# Why isn't __add__ implemented in Python's deque?

Tags: python, python-internals

Concatenating two `deque`s results in a `TypeError`.

```
from collections import deque
q = deque()
q + q
```

But `__iadd__` is implemented so `+=` is supported.

```
q1 = deque([1])
q2 = deque([2])
q1 += q2
```

What is the reason that only `__iadd__` get implemented?

Comment: [Starting in version 3.5, deques support `__add__()`, `__mul__()`, and `__imul__()`.](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.deque) See also [issue 23793](https://bugs.python.org/issue23793).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [a bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue23793) which is already fixed in the repos, so it should be included in the next released version of Python (3.5).